# Есть ли возможность замерить температуру, влажность воздуха и уровень CO2 телефоном? Хочется сделать метеостанцию домашнюю

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть ли возможность замерить температуру, влажность воздуха и уровень CO2 телефоном? Хочется сделать метеостанцию домашнюю.
может отдельно можно датчики прикупить для планшета?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да при наличии соответствующих датчиков у телефон. Соответствующие интерфейсы обязывает предоставлять спецификация ос.
 Иначе используються внешние датчики в связке с каким либо поддерживаемыми телефоном  способом передачи данных. И соответствующая программная обертка ввода вывода данных. 
Очень простое решение можно построить над ардруиновскими датчиками и к примеру WIFI модулем протокол UPD будет опять же к месту

Comment: спасибо буду изучать